# RxSwift: Completing observable sequence of unknown length

Tags: swift, observable, rx-swift

### Problem

I am trying to load all of the data my application needs before using. Once I have all of the data I want to emit one event back to my subscription in my controller with either a success or failure status.

I am struggling to come up with a way to send an onComplete status on my observable chain so I can use `toArray()`. Maybe there's a way or just a better approach that I have not thought of.

### Loading Workflow

Basically I have three different services: version, champion, and skin.

I retrieve the latest version and get all of the champions for that version. Then I download all of the images for each skin the champion has.

### Observable Chain

My observable chain in my LoadingViewModel is something like this:

```
return versionService.getLatest().flatMap({ (version: VersionData) in
    return championService.getChampions(forVersion: version)
}).flatMap({ (champions: [Champion]) -> Observable<Champion> in
    // Go through champions and update total skin count
    // emit each champion
}).flatMap({ (champion: Champion) -> Observable<Skin> in
    return skinService.getSkin(forChampion: champion)
}).toArray() // Doesn't work since I don't send complete
.flatMap({ (result: [Skin]) -> Observable<LoadingViewModelResult> in
    return Observable.just(LoadingViewModelResult.success)
})
```

If I don't have the toArray() there then I emit a `LoadingViewModelResult.success` for each skin which floods my view controller with an abundance of unwanted successful results.

#### What I've Tried

I attempted to use `.take(count)` where I passed in the skin count but since it is initialized to 0 the chain will instantly take 0 and return.

Answer (score 0):

For my `[Champion] -> Observable<Champion>` and `Champion -> Observable<Skin>` observables I needed to include an `observer.onCompleted` within the creation of the `Observable`.